# How to add iframe ads below title in blogspot?

Tags: iframe, title, blogspot

i want to add an iframe ads in one of my blogspot blog below the title in a single post, i find the solution to put the ads before these line of code :

```
<data:post.body/>
```

So my ads code is just like this :

```
<iframe src="http://myblog.com/display?ref=0000&q=KEYWORD&smart_ad_id=002" width="200" height="200" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>

<data:post.body/>
```

That was an easy step, but i got a problem when i want to add the title to replace the "KEYWORD" line inside those iframe. The code to call the title is here :

```
<data:post.title/>
```

When i add those line of code to replace the "keyword" line in my iframe code, i got an error :

```
<iframe src="http://myblog.com/display?ref=0000&q=<data:post.title/>&smart_ad_id=002" width="200" height="200" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Can anyone gives me solution on this, thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I checked your post and also used your code in my blog. And I figured out that you can add  in blogger template but the external link(http://myblog.com/display?ref=0000&q=KEYWORD&smart_ad_id=002) contains equal signs(=) which aren't acceptable So you can't add the above iframe instead of it you can use other which doesn't contain the equal sign.